# Outlook 365 Windows 11 minimize to system tray

Tags: microsoft-outlook, windows-11

As a long time user of Outlook I value the minimize to system tray feature. Having just bought a new computer with Windows 11 I find that the 'minimize to system tray' feature has disappeared. Any suggestions on how to bring it back/make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows 11 function for Outlook is called "Hide When Minimized.

This works. See the screen shot.

Check also in Settings, Systems, Notifications to see if Notifications may be involved. I do not think so but check.

Also check Hidden Icons to see if Office was, in fact, minimized and is hiding.  Click the UP Arrow ^ in the System Tray.

[image: Outlook Hide when Minimized]

Comment: It was already in the tray - thanks - I completely missed it